# Dreamweaver CC (2017) Hinting doesnt work outside file with <link> include

Tags: php, css, dreamweaver

the question is simple.
Dreamveaver 2017 is not showing any class hints under my condition.

BECAUSE: My php website structure dynamically include content from other files.
CSS stylesheet and footer JS scripts are included from different files.

f.eg. family tree looks like this:

```
/index.php

<?php include_once("/headerscripts.php"); ?>
```

and

```
/headerscripts.php

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Hinting works fine inside the "headerscripts.php" but doesnt work inside "index.php".

And this is the issue. I want the hints show no matter of family-tree child level.

(site folder and server are configured properly - it is dynamically showing me all the info and structure)

Comment: Change the IDE :), Seriously there are very cool and light IDEs. Try VS Code.

Comment: This is a dreamweaver issue, not a coding or PHP issue.

Comment: People still use Dreamweaver!?

Comment: I got used to it :) :(